# trouble with populating an image tag with xmlthttp.resonse

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Hi
i have a php page echoing some text and an image. I want the text to go to a div tag and the image to go to a separate img tag. Right now I can get both but they both show up in the div tag. I want them in their own tags.

Background Info = code:html, jscript = this is an html page that is separate from the host php page.

Code:

```
html =  <img. id="sourceImage" alt="" src=""  align="left" /><div id="txtHint"><b>this is where the info should go</b></div>

jScript = function Button2_onclick(){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("sourceImage").scr=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://ishopstark.com/mobileapp.php?category=1",true);

  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Should we guess what response you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("sourceImage").scr
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("sourceImage").src
```